# In react-native-gifted-chat how do I remove the line above the Composer component?

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

How do I remove this line? It doesn't seem to be a part of the Composer component.

[image: gifted chat image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Got help in the project's [Github issues](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/issues/1631).

```js
import { GiftedChat, InputToolbar } from 'react-native-gifted-chat';

<GiftedChat
  renderInputToolbar={(props) => (
    <InputToolbar {...props} containerStyle={{borderTopWidth: 0}} />
  )}
  // ... all the other props.
/>
```